# How to use a count based on 2 tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have one table which lists jobs and another table which lists applications for a job. I want to make a view where i list all the job details from the job table and have one column where there is a count of the number of applications for the job.

So far, i have done the above. The problem is that jobs with no applications do not appear at all whereas they should appear just with a count of 0. This is likely because a job with no applicants wont have any job_id listed in the application table.

```
select count(a.job_id) "no. of applicants",
       p.job_id,  
       p.status,
       p.JOB_TYPE,
       p.EMPLOYER_ID,
from application a 
join job p 
on a.job_id=p.job_id 
where p.status='OPEN' 
group by p.job_id, 
       p.status,
       p.JOB_TYPE,
       p.EMPLOYER_ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to switch tables - select from "job" and join "application", like so:

```sql
select count(a.job_id) "no. of applicants",
       p.job_id,  
       p.status,
       p.JOB_TYPE,
       p.EMPLOYER_ID,
from job a 
join application p 
on a.job_id=p.job_id 
where p.status='OPEN' 
group by p.job_id, 
       p.status,
       p.JOB_TYPE,
       p.EMPLOYER_ID;
```

Another solution is to use a subquery for calculating no. of applicants, but because you want just status='OPEN', which is in "application" table, you'd have to join it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

That would be **OUTER JOIN**, I presume. I simplified your tables (didn't feel like typing that much, as you didn't provide test case).

```
SQL> with
  2  application (job_id) as
  3    (select 1 from dual union all
  4     select 2 from dual
  5    ),
  6  job (job_id, status) as
  7    (select 1, 'OPEN'   from dual union all
  8     select 2, 'CLOSED' from dual union all
  9     select 3, 'OPEN'   from dual           --> no application for this job
 10    )
 11  select count(a.job_id) no_of_applicants,
 12    p.job_id,
 13    p.status
 14  from job p left join application a on p.job_id = a.job_id   --> LEFT (OUTER) JOIN
 15  group by p.job_id, p.status;

NO_OF_APPLICANTS     JOB_ID STATUS
---------------- ---------- ------
               1          2 CLOSED
               0          3 OPEN          --> job with no applications
               1          1 OPEN

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

this might help:

```
select isnull(count(a.job_id),0) "no. of applicants",
   p.job_id,  
   p.status,
   p.JOB_TYPE,
   p.EMPLOYER_ID,
from application a 
right join job p 
on a.job_id=p.job_id 
where p.status='OPEN' 
group by p.job_id, 
   p.status,
   p.JOB_TYPE,
   p.EMPLOYER_ID;
```

Comment: i changed the join to right join and added an isnull

Answer (score 0):

You want a `left join` so you keep all jobs that match the `where` conditions:

```
select j.job_id, j.status, j.JOB_TYPE, j.EMPLOYER_ID,
       count(a.job_id) as num_applicants
from job j left join
     application a 
     on a.job_id = j.job_id 
where j.status = 'OPEN' 
group by j.job_id, j.status, j.JOB_TYPE, j.EMPLOYER_ID;
```

That said, you might find that a correlated subquery is easier to express the logic:

```
select j.*
       (select count(*)
        from application a
        where a.job_id = j.job_id
       ) as num_applications
from job j
where j.status = 'OPEN'
```